# How to Decompiling Apk files that Generated By Android Studio

Tags: xml-parsing, apk, apktool

I have lost my android studio project completely and there is no way to get it back.
Now, I'm trying to decompile my apk file to access my java classes and xml files.

using `dex2jar` and `jd-gui`, I get my java classes BUT non of programs that I tested.So far, I can't decompile my xml files!

apktool show me this error:

> Exception in thread "main" brut.androlib.err.UndefinedResObject: could not decode arsc file

do i have to create all of my xml again? or there any way to decompile apks that generated by android studio?

Edit: "Apk Studio" Give me same error with apktool for decompiling apk file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To decompile the XML files you can use the following tools:

1. `JadX` - https://github.com/skylot/jadx
2. `Apktool` - https://github.com/iBotPeaches/Apktool

Remember the `apktool` which you are using is probably a very old version. Download the latest version of `apktool.jar` from `https://github.com/iBotPeaches/Apktool/releases/download/2.1.1/apktool_2.1.1.jar`

Below are the two process through which you can get the xml files.

#### `Apktool` Method:

1. Download the latest apktool jar from https://github.com/iBotPeaches/Apktool/releases/download/2.1.1/apktool_2.1.1.jar
2. Run it using `java -jar apktool.jar d <apkfile.apk>` without the angular brackets and substituting `apkfile.apk` with the actual path to the apk file

#### `Jadx` method:

1. Download the latest release of jadx from https://github.com/skylot/jadx/releases
2. Unzip the file and then goto `bin/` folder
3. Windows user can double click the `jadx-gui.bat` file
4. Linux/Mac users can run the shell script `./jadx-gui`
5. This will open jadx gui through which you can open the apk file.

**Reference**: `Jadx` open dialogue

[image]